# Printf Fprintf outputorder

Tags: c++, printf, output

I don't get why "cout" outputs after the file is written, it makes no sense to me... How would I do it correctly? I tried with sleep between the two, but it's still not reversing the order like I want to.

```
  cout << "Writing to file";
  fp = fopen("plume_visualisation.txt","w");
  for(int i=0;i<grid;i++)
    for(int j=0;j<grid;j++)
      for(int k=0;k<grid;k++)
    fprintf(fp,"%f\t%f\t%f\t%f\n",x[i],y[j],z[k],suv[i][j][k]);
  fclose(fp);
```

Comment: It's called *buffering*. Output to `std::cout` is buffered, and will not be written to the console until the buffer is flushed. And does it really matter? What problem do you have if the output to `std::cout` is written a little later than you expect?

Comment: Although (as described by SPD) this is likely true, I'm curious how you observed it? The difference should generally not even be noticeable in this given program.

Comment: On a slightly related note... If you're programming in C++, why don't you use C++ streams for the files as well?

Comment: The buffer can be flushed with the help of endl (will also produce a new line, though).

Comment: `<< std::flush` to avoid that

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit the for loop is looping over approximately 1e9 values :D

Comment: @GerardJúlio: lol ok fair enough

Comment: See also `cout.flush()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ writes to the output stream, stored in a buffer. You need to flush the buffer to write it to the console. Remember how you probably learned to write a line to the console?

```
std::cout << "This is a message" << std::endl;
```

What std::endl does is place a newline character at the end of the message, and flush the buffer. Based on your code, I'm guessing you thought "Hey, I can just leave off endl and it won't write a new line." This is a good way to think...but you probably didn't realize that endl also flushes the buffer. This is what you want:

```
std::cout << "Writing to file" << std::flush;
```

Also notice how I prefixed cout and flush with "std." Using "using namespace standard" is bad practice that you should avoid.

---

On a related note, you're already using C++. Instead of doing file IO the old C way of fprintf, instead set up a file stream. It works pretty much the same way that console IO does. Here's a great guide on how to do what you're doing in a more idiomatic fashion: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/

Comment: Thanks! I really only learned c in school and university, so I'm basically never using cout but printf, it did the same thing though

Comment: You have upvote, but "You need to flush the buffer to screen before it's written." rubs the wrong way a bit. I propose something more like "You need to flush the buffer to write it to the console."